# ORA-01017 Invalid username/password - Password/Username is correct

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ora-01017

I have created an oracle database on the Application express from oracle database 11g express edition, now while trying to connect to it through toad for oracle (or visual studio) I get the error

```
ORA-01017: Invalid username/password;logon denied.
```

I use the same username/password to connect to the application express and get acces to the database. I don't know what's wrong.

I changed the `tnsnames.ora`:

```
OFFICEMEMO =
    (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = (my host))(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
```

but I don't think this is the problem because it already says invalid username/password.

Comment: Are you certain that you created a database user (i.e. you ran a `CREATE USER` statement) rather than creating an application express (APEX) user?  An APEX user cannot log in to the database directly and a database user cannot generally log in to APEX.

Comment: When I try to do this, I get 'insufficient rights' do you know where I can change this in the APEX? I can't seem to find it.. I think your answer is probably right.. I feel kind of stupid right now..

Comment: I move it up in the tnsnames.ora and it worked..